# Navigation Based app : refreshing UIElements when controller is no more the current controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uielement

My app use a custom navigation controller.

When I push UIVIewController up on the navigation stack I have to load data over the network.

I use :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {

});
```

to load my data so the app is still responsive and so the user can press the back button which uses :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

When data has been loaded I often refresh `UIElement`s like UITableView, UILabel... when we press the `pushBack` button the controller is no more the current controller so when the elements are refreshed everything crashes.

So I have two questions :

- How can i know if the controller where the refresh is set is the current controller or not ?
- I think i have miss something, does Apple did not know it would happen and they have a probably set something for it ?

Thank you for any help, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show a activity indicator while you are loading the data . Till the time data is getting loading do not allow the user to pop the current view controller . this could be implemented by adding a transparent view to the current on the top and remove the transparent view soon after the loading is completed . This functionality could easily be implemented using MBProgressHUD .

Here is the Link : https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: i do not want my user to wait for loading !

Comment: In that case you can take a Flag which will notify whether user is on the current view or not . In the ViewWillAppear pass the value TRUE for that flag , as soon as the ViewWillDisappear: is called pass the value as FALSE for that flag . Also before populating (or refreshing) the UITableView check whether the value for the flag is TRUE or not

Comment: i tought about that, that is a good iedea, but i do not understand why apple did not handle this situation . . . thank you very much